# Get the email of the current recipient, Django

Tags: python, django, sendmail

I am building a blog app using django. It's a simple blog so it doesn't have a sign-in/sign-up function, but people can leave comments on posts using emails. And things go something like this:

1- Person leaves a comment on a post.
2- Once the comment is saved Person gets added to the subscription list of that post(only if they're not already on that list) so I could notify them when new comments are added to the post. 
3- Send emails to people on the subscription list notifying them of the new comment, and with the email, there's a link to let people unsubscribe from receiving further emails.

The problem I am facing right now is that I can't figure out how to fetch the recipient's email to pass it to the unsubscribe view instead of asking them to write it in an input field.

```
def unsubscribe_from_post(request, slug, email): #I don't how to know the email of the recipient to  pass it
    post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)           #to this function without asking them to write it down
    post.recipients.filter(recipient_email=email).delete()
```

in models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
title    = models.CharField(max_length=120)
body     = models.TextField()
pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', related_name= 'posts')
slug = models.SlugField(null=True)
recipients = models.ManyToManyField('Recipient') 

def __str__(self):
    return self.slug

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('blog:post_detail_view', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})  

class Recipient(models.Model):
    recipient_email = models.EmailField()

   def __str__(self):
       return self.recipient_email
```

in views.py

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    ''' Hadnel the http POST method '''  
    post = self.get_queryset(**kwargs)[0]
    self.object = self.get_object()  

    comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)

    if comment_form.is_valid():
        email = comment_form.cleaned_data["email"]
        name = comment_form.cleaned_data["name"]
        comment_msg= comment_form.cleaned_data["comment"]
        comment = Comment(name=name,
                          email= email,
                          comment=comment_msg,
                          post=post,
                          )
        comment.save()

        set_of_recipients = set(
                 recipient.recipient_email for recipient in post.recipients.all() if recipient.recipient_email != email
                 )

        if set_of_recipients:
           self.notify_recipients_of_new_comment(set_of_recipients, post, name, comment_msg)

        if email not in post.recipients.all():
           self.add_new_recipient(post, email) 

    return render(request, self.template_name, self.get_context_data(**kwargs))                    

def notify_recipients_of_new_comment(self, set_of_recipients, post, name, comment):
    from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
    from django.template import loader
    subject = "A new comment from Voila"
    html_template = loader.get_template('blog/email-template.html')
    context = {
        "name": name,
        "post": post,
        "comment": comment,
    }
    text_content = "hello there"
    html_content = html_template.render(context)
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, "zzanjabeel7@gmail.com", set_of_recipients)
    msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    return msg.send() 

def add_new_recipient(self, post, email):
    recipient = Recipient(recipient_email=email)
    recipient.save()
    post.recipients.add(recipient)
```

in urls.py

```
path('unsubscribe/<slug>', views.unsubscribe_from_post, name= "unsubscribe_from_post_view")
```

in temp.html

```
<h2>To unsubscribe <a href="http://localhost:8000{% url 'blog:unsubscribe_from_post_view' post.slug %}">click here</a></h2>
```

Thanks a lot.